# Return an array from the Method

Tags: angular

I'm trying to return the 'scorearray' array in this method, but what I'm getting is something called a 'subscriber'. I'm new to all this. Please help.

My method:

```
public GetScores():any {
// var result = await this.topbarService.getPatientData();
var patientID = "DummyID 1"//result.Data.Demographics.Identifers.patientID;
var apiUrl = 'questionaire/GetPatientHistory'
return this.http.post(apiUrl, { Id: patientID }).subscribe(data => {
  var data2: any = data;
  var scorearray = []
  for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
    var objtemp = data2[i]
    scorearray.push(objtemp.score)
  }
  return scorearray
});
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The `HttpClient` service generally returns an RxJS `Observable`, which is what `post` returns here. You can `subscribe` to an `Observable`, which executes the request and performs the callback function on receiving a response.

You should leave subscribing to the latest moment possible, and preferably only subscribe in the HTML file using the `async` pipe (more on that later). To achieve what you're trying to do here, it's better to use the `pipe` method, which allows you to transform the received data. `pipe` produces a new `Observable` which can be subscribed to later.

`pipe` takes `operators` as arguments which will be executed on the received data. The most common is `map` which simply takes the data, and returns something else. That's the only operator we need in this case. More info here: https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators

```js
  getScores(): Observable<any[]> {
    const patientID = 'DummyID 1';
    const apiUrl = 'questionaire/GetPatientHistory';
    return this.http
      .post<any[]>(apiUrl, { Id: patientID })
      .pipe(map((data: any[]) => data.map((objTemp) => objTemp.score)));
  }
```

I've streamlined your callback function into the one liner `data.map((objTemp) => objTemp.score)`. That's using the `Array.map()` function, not to be confused with the `map` RxJS operator. As a side note `var` is legacy code that should be avoided. Use `const` when possible and `let` otherwise.

---

Notice how this function returns an `Observable`, so to get the data you need to subscribe somehow. The simplest way to do that is to assign the `Observable` to a variable and use the `async` pipe in HTML. To show you how it's normally done, I'll put this function in a service as well.

**Service**

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/map';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getScores(): Observable<any[]> {
    const patientID = 'DummyID 1';
    const apiUrl = 'questionaire/GetPatientHistory';
    return this.http
      .post<any[]>(apiUrl, { Id: patientID })
      .pipe(map((data: any[]) => data.map((objTemp) => objTemp.score)));
  }
}
```

**Component TS**

```js
export class OneComponent {
  constructor(private ms: MyService) {}
  scoreArray = new Observable<any[]>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.scoreArray = this.ms.getScores();
  }
}
```

**Component HTML**

```html
<pre>{{ scoreArray | async | json }}</pre>
```

---

Here's an example using the jokes API https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wuwtqv?file=src/app/my.service.ts

Answer (score -1):

You can return Oberservation by return this.http.post(apiUrl, { Id: patientID }). then you can call subscribe if you actually wanna get the data.